# Wordpress 301 redirect in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Where to place rewrite conditions in .htaccess so Wordpress won't overwrite them time to time? And should it be placed before or after WP part? It should work for Google Analytics redundant hostnames.

These two lines should be placed outside WP part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works perfect but gets overwritten by WP:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: To redirect a single post or page, add the following short snippet for each post or page you want to redirect:

`Redirect 301 /old-url https://yourdomain.com/new-url`

Where /old-url is only the part that comes after yourdomain.com. For the new URL, you should input the full URL, though.

For example, to 301 redirect `www.yourdomain.com/301-post` to `www.yourdomain.com/how-to-redirect`, you would add this code:

Redirect 301 /301-post `https://yourdomain.com/how-to-redirect`

Comment: Its a non-www URL to www redirection as shown above.
And the issue is that WP each time something is changed in settings the code is overwritten. So where to place my redirect according to WP standard rewrite? Thanks!

Comment: You can put the code in `.htaccess` @Robibob

Comment: Yes of course in the .htaccess. The question was where to place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution myself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wobblingwilly.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.wobblingwilly.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```